# Add Resources to an Xcode Project Recursively with Applescript

Tags: iphone, xcode, applescript

Is it possible to add a folder to an Xcode project as a group with Applescript, recursively adding everything below it as if it were dragged to the Groups & Files list?

Comment: +1 just to push you over 1.5k :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed all files in subdirectories, apart from lproj directories, to be flat in the .app bundle. The assets were in this structure:

```
${assetsDir}/${targetCode}/
    Icon.png
    en.lproj
    ja.lproj
    ...
    *.lproj
    resources{$targetCode/
        Target.plist
        audio/Audio.plist
             *.mp3
```

I added a Run Script build phase prior to "Copy Bundle Resources" with something similar to following:

```
COPY_COMMAND="$DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp"
copyPNGCommand="$PLATFORM_DEVELOPER_LIBRARY_DIR/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copypng"

lprojDirectories=$( find ${assetsDirectory}/${targetCode} -type d -name *lproj )

for lprojDirectory in $lprojDirectories; do
    "$COPY_COMMAND" -exclude .DS_Store -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks "$lprojDirectory"  "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
done

MP3s=$( find ${assetsDirectory}/${targetCode}/resources${targetCode} -type f -name *.mp3 )

for MP3 in $MP3s; do
    filename=$( basename "$PNG" )
    "$COPY_COMMAND" -resolve-src-symlinks "$MP3"  "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
done

PNGs=$( find ${assetsDirectory}/${targetCode}/resources${targetCode} -type f -name *.png )

for PNG in $PNGs; do
    if [ -x "$copyPNGCommand" ]; then
        filename=$( basename "$PNG" )
        "$copyPNGCommand" -compress "" "$PNG" "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH/$filename"
    else
        "$COPY_COMMAND" -resolve-src-symlinks "$PNG" "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
    fi
done

Plists=$( find ${assetsDirectory}/${targetCode}/resources${targetCode} -type f -name '*.plist' )

for Plist in $Plists; do
    "$XCODE_APP_SUPPORT_DIR/Plug-ins/CoreBuildTasks.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/copyplist" --convert binary1 "$Plist" --outdir "$CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR/$UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH"
done
```

Note: copypng only works when building for the device, hence the test

Answer (score 2):

I don't do exactly that, but I do a very similar thing. I run the following shell command as a post-build command: (I've broken it into several lines so it's easier to read)

```
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
   -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks
   $FOLDER $APP_FOLDER
```

This command copies `$FOLDER` to your app, and `$APP_FOLDER` is the location of the (built) `.app` folder, *not* the Xcode project. For example, my command expands out to

```
/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp
   -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -resolve-src-symlinks
   /Users/beder/src/myproj/data
   /Users/beder/src/myproj/build-iphone/Debug-iphonesimulator/Myproj.app
```

(My build system uses CMake, which is why the `.app` folder is in a bit of an unconventional location.)

The net result is that the data folder is copied to the `.app` folder (as you would expect - `../Myproj.app/data/`). This bypasses copying it to Xcode, but I've found that I have no need for the folder to appear in Xcode. After each build, it copies the folder, so I can use the files in it as if I had dragged the folder to Xcode.

Obviously this isn't applescript, but you can execute a shell command in applescript by

```
do shell script "whatever"
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this may be the answer. I'll mark it as correct when I've had a chance to test.

Comment: I will reply in another answer as to what I eventually did, but thanks, you certainly got me there!